# Resize PyGame Video

Tags: python, video, resize, pygame

I have a video that is in 240x160 and I intend for the user to be able to change their resolution to a few different sizes (as seen in the source) in the final game. I read on the [docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pygame/latest/pygame.pdf) and they said that the video should automagically resize however in my experience it has not. Here is my source code:

```
import pygame

#Scales
GAMEBOY         = 1        #240x160  (Standard gameboy resolution)
FOUREIGHTYP     = 2        #480x320  (480p resolution)
SEVENTWENTYP    = 4        #960x640  (720p resolution)
TENEIGHTYP      = 6        #1440x960 (1080p resolution)

chosenScale = SEVENTWENTYP

resolution = (240*chosenScale, 160*chosenScale)

FPS = 60

movie1Counter = 0
movie2Counter = 1

movie1Playing = True
movie2Playing = False
playedEarly = False
earlyCounter = 0

keypressed = False

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.quit()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie1.mpg')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(movie.get_size())

movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()

movie.set_display(movie_screen)

movie.play()
movie.set_volume(0.5)

playing = True
while playing:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            movie1.stop()
            playing = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                if movie1Playing:
                    movie.stop()
                    playedEarly = True
                    movie1Playing = False
                    movie2Playing = True
                    movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
                    movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
                    movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()
                    movie.set_display(movie_screen)
                    movie.play()
                    movie.set_volume(0)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            pass

    if movie.get_busy() == 0:
        if movie1Playing == True:
            movie.stop()
            movie1Playing = False
            movie2Playing = True
            movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
            movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
            movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()
            movie.set_display(movie_screen)
            movie.play()
            movie.set_volume(0.5)
        else:
            movie.stop()
            movie1Playing = True
            movie2Playing = False
            movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie1.mpg')
            movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie1.mpg')
            movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size())
            movie.set_display(movie_screen)
            movie.play()
            movie.set_volume(0.5)

    if playedEarly:
        earlyCounter += 1
        if earlyCounter > 67:
            movie.set_volume(0.5)
            playedEarly = False
            earlyCounter = 0

    screen.blit(movie_screen,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Sorry about the length, I'm new to PyGame and I'm not sure what you guys need to solve the issue. Also, I have tried changing screen and movie_screen however if I make the resolution of the window any larger than the video then it just sits in the top left corner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you wondering how this may be accomplished, instead of resizing your window in pygame an alternative approach would be to have different videos that fit your resolution. If you have ffmpeg installed then this is really easy. This is the command I used to solve my problem:

```
ffmpeg -i infile -target ntsc-vcd -vcodec mpeg1video -s WIDTHxHEIGHT -sws_flags neighbor outfile
  - Where infile is the file (including the extension) you converting with
  - Where WIDTHxHEIGHT is the desired resoution of the outfile (ex: 480x320)
  - Where outfile is the file (including the extension) that is generated
```

Note that if the video you are trying to generate needs to have a high bit-rate then you'll get lots of "error" messages flying by in ffmpeg however you don't need to worry about this for pygame's purposes. Despite having lots of errors pygame seems to play these files flawlessly, however your standard media player will not fare as well with lots of frame drops.

Hope this helps, happy coding!